# Avro Schema Java validation API

Tags: java, avro

Is there a Java API that would verify whether a submitted text is a valid Avro schema?
I think one can generate a class file invoking:

`java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.9.2.jar compile schema <schema file> <destination>`

But I am looking for more in-process programmatic validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it solves the problem to run

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/tool/DataFileGetSchemaTool.html

"in-process".